# What search engine to use?

Tags: sql, search, symfony1, search-engine

I'm building a web application with the Symfony Framework. The purpose of this app is to book an hotel, which is part of several hotels.

The user have to choose in which hotel he wants to go, and by selecting the date, how many adults, child and rooms they want, the app have to display the available flat left in the hotel matching the criterias.

My question is : What is the best way to achieve that ? Basic SQL request or search engine like solr or zend lucene ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a basic SQL query to me.